# Is it possible to create a pem file server certificate from the result of openssl s_client -showcerts?

Tags: openssl, curl, solaris

I know it is possible to list server certificates from a client via `openssl s_client -showcerts`.

So, my question is, is it possible to create a valid ssl server certificate from this without needing to contact the server admin?

I have control of my client machine but not of the server so if I can avoid it, it would save trouble. I believe I need a .pem file and need a root certificate since using curl to access the server results in `unable to get local issuer certificate`.

If it not possible to do it, a kind application of why it is not possible would be appreciated, as am a bit out of my depth here. It seems to me only logical that it would be possible as the server has provided its certificate already.

`openssl s_client -showcerts` also outputs these errors:

```
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

In essence, I would like to be able to make ssl as a client trust the server I am connecting to.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a valid ssl server certificate" ? One you could use to create your own SSL server? Then you would also need the private key for the certificate which the server does not provide.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the error `unable to get local issuer certificate` from curl from a client and don't have server control, and as far as i understand its possibly indicating I have to add a root CA or some sort of server certificate. In openssl it says `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** your `curl` was built to use OpenSSL -- as you tagged but which is not the only option for `curl`, verify with `curl -V` -- **AND** the server is correctly serving any/all intermediate cert(s), **THEN** to trust the server **curl-with-openssl needs a local 'truststore' containing the root cert** for the server's cert chain (NOT the server's cert itself) in PEM format. (Some other SSL/TLS implmentations will accept nonroot anchor(s), but older versions of OpenSSL cannot do so at all, and even 1.0.2 doesn't  do so by default.)

**METHOD 0: maybe already there.** *Packages* of curl often include a 'bundle' of widely-trusted CA roots such as Symantec GoDaddy etc., or link to another package that does (typically named something like ca-bundle or trusted-cas). The format(s) of the certs in such a bundle depend on the SSL/TLS library(ies) you use; check `curl -V` as above. Check if you have such a bundle installed, and if so whether your `curl` is using it. If you don't have or can't get a package (including the case you build curl yourself) AND use OpenSSL, [curl upstream has a bundle of CA roots extracted from Mozilla NSS/Firefox](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) extracted into the concatenated-PEM format needed for OpenSSL (and a tool to do this yourself).

`openssl` commandline need not use the same default truststore location(s) as `curl` -- and even if it does, until recent versions the `s_client` command had a bug that didn't *use* the default truststore correctly. If you do have a concatenated-PEM bundle, specify it to `s_client` with `-CAfile bundlefile` and see if that makes a difference.

If method 0 doesn't apply, you need to get the server's root and add it to your truststore, or just use it as a truststore by itself.

**METHOD 1: get from browser.** IF you can connect to the server with a browswer like IE/Edge, Firefox, Chrome, etc. (this requires there be a URL you can enter that the server will respond with a successful webpage), THEN doubleclick on the padlock and click on whichever buttons or links lead to displaying the certificate *chain* (exact ones vary per browser). Select the topmost cert in the chain and look for an option to export it, preferably in single-cert PEM format (again exact method varies per browser). If you can't get single-cert PEM format, comment what format you did get (give the first line if it looks like `-----BEGIN something`) and I'll tell you how to convert it.

Take this file (copy to the `curl` machine if you created it somewhere else) and either add it to your truststore (depends on your packaging system; may be a simple as concatenating it to the existing concatenated-PEM file) or specify it by itself to `curl` with option `--cacert filename`.

**METHOD 2: s_client plus.** Run `openssl s_client -connect host:port -showcerts` and capture (redirect or scrape) the output. Take the *last* block of lines `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `----END CERTIFICATE-----` and put it in a file, for example `topcert`. If the `s:` and `i:` names (subject and issuer) immediately preceding this block are *exactly* the same, this is the root cert and you're all set. Use this file as above, but only if you are satisified this CA is honest and competent (even though they apparently didn't convince the browser makers if method 1 didn't work) because you are putting the security of your data in their hands.

If the top cert from the server is not a root, you need to get its *parent* cert, which must be the root. Alternatively, in some cases this is a 'bridge' or 'transition' cert that links a new CA back to another (older) CA, and there is also a *sibling* cert for the new CA that is a root cert. First do `openssl x509 -in topcert -noout -text` and look under `x509v3 extensions` then `Authority Information Access` for `CA Issuers`. If present, accessing this URL (or any of them) should provide the parent cert. This is usually in DER format; if so convert with `openssl x509 -in input -inform der -out output`.

Otherwise, look at any OCSP address(es), any CRL Distribution Point(s), and any URL(s) or domain name(s) in Certificate Policies or the Issuer name for the domain name(s) used by the CA and poke around there to try to find the parent root. Similarly look at any URL(s) or domain name(s) in Policies or Subject name and poke around for a sibling root. Or google for the Issuer name and/or Subject name. Or post the cert here. Or some combination.

Comment: After a lot of poking around, I managed to figure out how to properly add an item the truststore. But this wasn't the only issue. It looks like my openssl is v0.97 which does not support the encoding of the certificate. Having figured out all of that now, I believe I know what I need to do.

Comment: I guess/hope you know 0.9.7 is at least 8 years old, depending on the letter which in OpenSSL is actually part of the version. Even so, cert *encoding* (both X.509 and openssl-PEM) hasn't really changed since 1997, so I'd expect that to work although it might ignore/skip newer extensions. The only thing I can think of offhand that probably wouldn't work is a cert using or for ECC *signature* i.e. ECDSA. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: solaris 10 has only got v0.97 built in, so I suppose anyone else with solaris 10 will be in the same situation. About the encoding, an error I have seen is with v0.97 is verify return code: 7 (certificate signature failure). I've read somewhere only SHA1 is supported.

Comment: Ouch! (0) I dug up some old versions and **you're right 0.9.7 doesn't have SHA2.** In addition to SHA1 it does have RIPEMD160, MD5, MD4 and MD2 -- but that's worse not better. I was also right it doesn't have ECDSA, but ECDSA is fairly easy to avoid today and SHA2 is not. (1) Per http://superuser.com/questions/649579/openssl-binary-for-solaris-10 there may be a newer openssl package for Sol 10. (2) Worst case, you can download source and build it yourself. I did one project using openssl on Sol 10 back around 2008, which for some reason I don't recall couldn't use sunfreeware, ...

Comment: ... so we built from source and it was only about an hour and worked fine. You would probably need to (re)build curl to use the new openssl, and I can't testify to that but I've heard it's not bad. FWTW.

Comment: ah. will try a build. But still a bit odd that there isn't a default provided. Thanks!

Comment: Our solaris 10 may have old openssl 0.9.7. but it seems to have had a lot of patches applied on top. (+ security fixes for: CVE-2005-2969 CVE-2006-2937 CVE-2006-2940 CVE-2006-3738 CVE-2006-4339 CVE-2006-4343 CVE-2006-7250 CVE-2007-5135 CVE-2007-3108 CVE-2008-5077 CVE-2008-7270 CVE-2009-0590 CVE-2009-2409 CVE-2009-3555 CVE-2010-4180 CVE-2011-4576 CVE-2011-4619 CVE-2012-0884 CVE-2012-1165 CVE-2012-2110 CVE-2012-2131 CVE-2012-2333 CVE-2013-0166 CVE-2013-0169 CVE-2014-0224 CVE-2014-3508 CVE-2014-3511 CVE-2014-3566 CVE-2014-3567 CVE-2014-3568 CVE-2014-3569 CVE-2014-3570 CVE ...